# What do Italians call the striped doorway curtains seen commonly in Burano and elsewhere?

Tags: regional, nouns, colloquial

Is there an Italian name for the doorway curtains found especially in towns in the Venice lagoon, such as Burano?

One suggestion was that they are called *tenda da sole a caduta*, however, I'm looking for the doorway coverings that you could pull aside, and *tenda da sole a caduta* seem to be more like awnings that are fixed in place at top and bottom.

Comment: I asked this [question on Stack Exchange travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166541/what-do-italians-call-the-striped-doorway-curtains-seen-commonly-in-burano-and-e), and it was suggested I might find better luck here.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: I'm not Italian, but I suspect it's ["tenda da sole a strisce"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tenda+da+sole+a+strisce%22&client=firefox-b-m&sxsrf=ALeKk030uHDvqwfNNbmnKHQLUvBLcuzUdg:1625328584609&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG3bbnpMfxAhWE0eAKHeibAOYQ_AUIBigB&biw=414&bih=757) or ["tenda da sole a righe"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tenda+da+sole+a+righe%22&client=firefox-b-m&sxsrf=ALeKk02vv3a5w-Q1Gyn2FxTdcnM6p3iGdA:1625328649992&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4sc2GpcfxAhXBBmMBHUOtCe0Q_AUIBigB&biw=414&bih=757) ("per esterno" or "da esterno").

Comment: It's an interesting question, although I'm not sure they have a specific name.

Comment: I add to my previous comment that I immagine that, sometimes, you may need to add some explanation to specify it doesn't need any kind of support structure, but "solamente anelli o ganci per appenderla". Maybe "una di quelle che sono pronte all'uso" ("una tenda pronta all'uso").

Comment: I am a native Italian speaker but I've never heard them called in any particular way. I'd say we simply refer to them as *tenda / tende* (curtain / curtains) and describe them in different ways, if we need to be more specific: for example "*tenda per porta*" (doorway curtain) or "*tenda da sole per porta*" (door awning). The type composed by many separate strips or thin ropes is usually referred to as "*tenda antimosche*" (fly-stopping curtain).

Comment: I consulted a Venetian friend who asked some people from Burano and was told they're called “tende pal sol” (in Italian “tende per il sole”).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean this kind of curtains:

[image]

Source https://www.fabionodariphoto.com/burano-lisola-dei-colori/

In Burano, according to people living there who were consulted by a friend of mine, they're called *tende pal sol*; in Italian *tende per il sole*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "official" name for such a kind of curtain.

Usually they are named "tende ciniglia" o "tende in ciniglia" from the name of the material, which is chenille fabric.

[image: chenille curtain]

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I don't think the question is referring to this kind of curtain.